# Как указать версию сайта Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

можно как то указать версию сайта в vue? Например version='01.01' и каким образом?
Например знаю что можно указывать версию `?ver=01` - типо такого

```
<script src="index.js?ver=01" defer=""></script>
```

Как это сделать с vue никак ни пойму, ни найду

Comment: версию сайта, которую я могу руками менять

Comment: `index.js?ver=01` — это гет запрос, поэтому для такого сайт должен быть на ноде или серверсайд рендеринг например Nuxt, а далее просто возвращаете то что нужно по этому запросу (например JSON ответ хотя это может быть странно, но если Вам нужно то ОК).

Comment: @DaniilLoban nuxt присутствует, но возвращать мне ничего не нужно, ?ver=01 - это делается для того, что бы файл не кэшировался, но я это хочу использовать и для того, что бы клиент видел версию, типо как спринт, который я могу задавать сама используя переменную

Comment: А чем именно не подошел ответ @versetty777 ?

Comment: @DaniilLoban то, что вуи рендерит свои скрипты, и вот туда надо запихать эту версию

Comment: Мне кажется, предложенный вариант наиболее правильным, в крайнем случае можно создать скрипт который сделает вставку в сгенеренные файлы `html` через `fs` — прочитать содержимое файлов найти через регулярку места для вставки версии, записать файл. Потому что, я сильно сомневаюсь что во `Vue` для этого существуют штатные средства, как я понимаю для обхода кэширования в любом из фремворков существуют хэшированные имена js файлов (каждый билд разные)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте файл .env:

```
VUE_APP_VERSION=01.01
```

Используйте переменную в коде:

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION)
```

В HTML файле можно использ. `VUE_APP_VERSION` для указания версии сайта:

```
<script src="index.js?ver={{process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION}}" defer=""></script>
```

Comment: к сожалению это не то что мне требуется

Answer (score 1):

В имя файла нельзя добавить символ `?`(нужно разбираться почему так),
но в запрос добавить можно.

Для vue 2 версии с webpack в файле `vue.config.js` укажите следующее:

```
const {defineConfig} = require('@vue/cli-service')

const version = '01'

module.exports = defineConfig({
    //для css
    css: {
        extract: {
            filename: 'css/[name]-v' + version + '.css?ver=' + version,
            chunkFilename: 'css/[name]-v' + version + '.css?ver=' + version
        },
    },
    //для js
    configureWebpack: (config) => {
        config.output.filename = 'js/[name]-v' + version + '.js?ver=' + version;
        config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name]-v' + version + '.js?ver=' + version;
    },
})
```

Файл будет называться `app-v01.js`, а в html он будет подключаться `src="/js/app-v01.js?ver=01"`